# Permalinks of New Pages and their Parents

Tags: permalinks, pages

I am running into a new issue where when I attempt to create a new page, the permalink is not being auto generated.

#### For instance

On the 'Add New Page' page, I select 'Our Club' as the parent (which has a slug of 'club'). I then type in 'Membership' as the title.  However, the permalink that is generated below the text input says `www.coolclub.com/membership` (instead of `www.coolclub.com/club/membership` as expected).

If, instead of select 'Clubhouse' as the parent of my new page (which is itself already linked as a child page of 'Our Club'), then the permalink is generated successfully.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the permalink not update after you click the Save Draft or Publish button?

Comment: No it doesn't - I have found though that after I create the page and update, if i come back and then move it to a new parent, the permalink is updated correctly.  But I still would like to make it work when I initially create the page - if there is a problem in my site I would rather fix it now as opposed to it causing some issues further down the line -

Comment: very strange. I suggest you try disabling plugins and switching to one of the default themes to see if it's possibly theme/plugin related. if the issue disappears, re-enable things one at a time until you narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: The information below is somewhat inaccurate. My mistake. The Page hierarchy *is* shown in permalinks, and the article I linked to discusses changing it in Posts. Thanks for the correction, @Milo.

### Original Post:

You may not like this answer, but WordPress doesn't include page hierarchy in urls. It is for use in your theme (menus, breadcrumbs...) only. So the behavior you are seeing is correct.

I did find an article discussing a way for you to *impose* that structure on a per-page basis. WordPress won't do it dynamically for you, but it can be done.

http://winkpress.com/essential/permalinks/

The plugin mentioned in that article can be found here:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Sorry that there doesn't seem to be a way to make it happen automatically. If you are savvy, you might be able to write a little something that talks to that plugin, but I really don't know if that is possible.

Comment: Sorry, this is incorrect. WordPress includes the hierarchy in the URL for the *page* post type. The site you linked describes creating hierarchy for the *post* post type.

Comment: Yea - so where is this behavior prescribed?  Is it written in PHP somewhere or is it in the .htaccess file?  I am a bit new to PHP/web programming (I'm a C# guy).